# Django with PostgreSQL 10?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-postgresql, postgresql-10

Does Django support PostgreSQL 10 at the moment? I tried to use pgadmin3 with the psql V10 and found, it breaks pdagmin3.

Somebody has opened a ticket on [django project](https://github.com/django/deps/issues/45) which may be in discussion.

Is there any known breaking changes in v10 compared to v9.6 for Django? (because it breaks in pgadmin3)?

let me know thanks.

Comment: Why don't you upgrade go pgAdmin 4 which is intended for Postgres 10?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name its uisuck to be honest, hate that default bootstrap looks. Well, that doesn't relate to my question as the question is specifically about django and postgres

Answer (score 1):

Django supports PostgreSQL 10 with Psycopg 2.7.3.2

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL 10 with latest version of Django and Psycopg2 2.7.3.2. But, I am unable to proceed. Getting this error on windows.
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.